# How can I run protractor e2e tests on skeleton-esnext-webpack without building the app?

Tags: protractor, aurelia

I've been using the skeleton navigation skeleton-esnext-webpack environment to run local tests on aurelia. However, sometimes I need to run my tests from a server already set up on the web. I'd like to keep the aurelia plugins intact but not wait so long for the local build to be built and ran since I already have it running elsewhere. The readme doesn't say much about how everything works.

Is there a way to temporarily run my tests while ignoring the local build and setup?

Answer (score 0):

Go the package.json file in the root and modify it as so:

```
"e2e": "concurrently --success first --kill-others \"npm run e2e:start\"",
```

You can even keep the original and rename it something else and have that as a local call and rename the above line to run it without building it.